# How to get rows without selected in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have an array of rows indices `(2, 5, 1,... )` I want to keep out from my dataframe. How to do such filtering in pandas?

Comment: Have you read a tutorial yet? This is covered pretty early on in the material: `df = df.drop(index_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `drop`

```
a=np.array([2,5,1,..])
df=df.drop(a)
```